# Kotlin not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing an app and just redo it from a youtube video to get back into app writing.

All this Kotlin is new to me as it didn't exist last time I programmed some apps.
When creating the new App I chose Kotlin instead of java.

Now I want to create a Constants class with a companion:

```
public class Constants {

    companion object {
        const BASE_URL = "https://whatever.com"
    }
}
```

But too many errors are shown:[Shown errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DouxO.png)

```
companion: cannot resolve

object: missing ;

const: unexpected token

BASE_URL: cannot resolve

string: missing ;
```

Furthermore, I have created a new class which should be a data class, but it doesn't recognize it as well:
[data class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDDZb.png)

I did install the KOTLIN plugins but it didn't help.

Comment: did you make a kotlin file instead of a java file ?